# Simple Python xlsx File Compare Without Metadata

Tags: python, pandas

Is there an easy way to compare two xlsx files in python that ignores metadata? Trying to test that the output of a script matches an expected xlsx file.

I'm looking for something like filecmp.cmp() which doesn't work because the metadata for the files differs (I think the only difference is that they were written at different times). I see some other people talking about reading the file with pandas, which is not what I want because I don't want the overhead (and I care about more than just the data).

Alternatively, if I can figure out exactly what metadata differs between the two, I could introduce a variable to make the script write a bogus test date (that matches that in the expected file) when it's run as part of my test suite.

EDIT: By specifying engine='xlsxwriter' in my writer = pd.ExcelWriter(...) call, I'm able to use xlsxwriter's set_properties method on writer.book:

writer.book.set_properties({'created': datetime.date(1936, 10, 31)}). This allows me to write the file each time with the same created date, and the simple filecmp.cmp() passes. I'd still love to hear if there's a way to avoid this because it's pretty hacky, but hey... it works...

Comment: Have you tried with `filecmp.cmp(shallow=False)` option. Please refer [filecmp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it looks like the part that's making it fail is internal to the xlsx files, so I need something that goes into the file a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two files like this

```
value1   value2   value3
0.456   3.456    0.4325436
6.24654 0.235435 6.376546
4.26545 4.264543 7.2564523
```

and

```
value1   value2  value3
0.456   3.456    0.4325436
6.24654 0.23546  6.376546
4.26545 4.264543 7.2564523
```

You can try something like this...

```
from itertools import izip_longest
import xlrd

rb1 = xlrd.open_workbook('file1.xlsx')
rb2 = xlrd.open_workbook('file2.xlsx')

sheet1 = rb1.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet2 = rb2.sheet_by_index(0)

for rownum in range(max(sheet1.nrows, sheet2.nrows)):
    if rownum < sheet1.nrows:
        row_rb1 = sheet1.row_values(rownum)
        row_rb2 = sheet2.row_values(rownum)

        for colnum, (c1, c2) in enumerate(izip_longest(row_rb1, row_rb2)):
            if c1 != c2:
                print "Row {} Col {} - {} != {}".format(rownum+1, colnum+1, c1, c2)
    else:
        print "Row {} missing".format(rownum+1)
```

This will display any cells which are different between the two files. For your given two files, this will display:

> Row 3 Col 2 - 0.235435 != 0.23546

Comment: This isn't really what I'm looking for. I just want a test that will return a true if the formatting and data in the two excel files are the same and false otherwise, but other metadata could be different.

Comment: Oh okay, try as @Nand has suggested in comments in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Xlsx files are a collection of XML files in a Zip container. For two xlsx files to be binary equivalent the:

1. XML files must be exactly the same.
2. The zip must be done in the same way.

For XlsxWriter files, and probably for most software, the zip will be the same. However, it may not be the same between software.

The XML part is less likely to be the same.

The first metadata difference can be the system timestamps on the files before they are zipped (since that data is stored in the zip). For versions of XlsxWriter >= 1.0.4 this timestamp is always '1980-01-01 00:00:00 ' like Excel so that will be the same.

Excel also adds metadata about the author and creation/modification times to the file so any two files save a fraction of a second apart will be different.

This metadata is stored in the 'docProps/core.xml' file within the XML collection:

```
$ xmllint --format example/docProps/core.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<cp:coreProperties xmlns:cp="...">
  <dc:creator>John</dc:creator>
  <cp:lastModifiedBy>John</cp:lastModifiedBy>
  <dcterms:created xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2018-02-23T21:20:58Z</dcterms:created>
  <dcterms:modified xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2018-02-25T02:13:23Z</dcterms:modified>
</cp:coreProperties>
```

In order to make these consistent in XlsxWriter you can set the `created` [document property](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#workbook-set-properties):

```
workbook.set_properties({'created':  datetime.date(2018, 1, 1))
```

This is the "hacky" method you refer to but it is actually valid. It allows a binary `cmp` style comparison.

XlsxWriter tries to have a very high level of compatibility with Excel so it has ~700 tests where it compared its output with files created by Excel. To do this it uses a test function called [`compare_xlsx_files()`](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/blob/master/xlsxwriter/test/helperfunctions.py#L229). This ignores the date style metadata when doing the comparison and also the order of some of the elements in other metadata "rel" files, which can vary. It also allows you to ignore certain files or elements with files when making the comparison. It isn't exported by the module but it is available if you need it.